# How do I make Tomcat accept SSL connections on port 8443?

Tags: tomcat

I installed Tomcat 9.0.40 on my Debian VPS, I have got a certificate and key from let's encrypt, but i can't make ssl/tls connection work. The only thing I did was changing the configuration file like this

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.tk/cert.pem" certificateKeyFile="/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.tk/privkey.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

What am I missing ? When accessing mydomain.tk:8443 my browser doesn't find it (but unsecure 8080 is working)

Comment: Q: The "configuration file" you modified  is `server.xml`, correct? Q: What do the logs say at Tomcat startup?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a text editor to open the Tomcat server.xml file.
   Typically, the server.xml file is in the conf folder in your
   Tomcat’s home directory.
2. Locate the connector you want the new Keystore to secure.
3. Usually, a connector with port 443 or 8443 is used; see step 4. Note
   that you may need to uncomment the connector – remove the comment
   tags ().
4. Configure your Tomcat connector.Make sure to specify your new keystore filename and password in your connector configuration.

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="100"
           minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server"
           keystoreFile="/home/user_name/your_site_name.jks"
           keystorePass="your_keystore_password" />
```

In the connector configuration above, keystoreFile is the full path to your keystore file, keystorePass is the password you used to create your keystore, and keyAlias is the same alias name (e.g., "server") that you used to generate your CSR.

5. Save your changes to the server.xml file.
6. Restart the Tomcat service.